# How can I get a list of all Google Sites shared with me?

Tags: sharing, google-classic-sites

Over at https://sites.google.com/, there are tabs for "My Sites" and "Deleted Sites", but I can't seem to find a way to list all sites to which I have access (those created by others).

Google Drive has a tab for "Shared with Me".  Is there a similar listing for Google Sites that are shared with me?